# angularjs calculate expression and assign to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have an expression in an ng-repeat that calculate various inputs in a table row and returns gross pay like so:

**Controller**

```
App.controller 'calcPayCtrl', ($scope, $filter, Api, employments) ->    

active_employments = $filter('filter')(employments, {status: 'active'})
$scope.employments = active_employments
angular.forEach $scope.employments, (employment) ->
    payslip = {employment_id: employment.id}
    employment.payslip = payslip
```

**VIEW**

```
<td>
   <input ng-model="row.payslip.hours_worked">
   <input ng-model="row.payslip.overtime_hours_worked">
</td>
<td>
   <h5>Gross Pay</h5>: {{ ((row.payslip.hours_worked*row.hourly_rate) || 0) + ((row.payslip.overtime_hours_worked*row.overtime_multiple) || 0 | currency: "" }}
</td>
```

The expression works as intended.

Now I'd like to take the result of the gross pay and assign it to a $scope model so I can save it to a Rails Api like so

```
row.gross_pay = gross_pay
```

How do I assign the result of the expression to the model?

Comment: You could move the calculation into the controller and assign when you calculate?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I don't know how to do so for an array however. Any tips or sample code that you can point me to?

Comment: @Ryan.lay, Can you post the controller code where you are fetching `rows`

Comment: This isn't JS... Maybe CoffeeScript?

Comment: Yup it's coffeescript

Comment: @Ryan.lay I've provided you a sample solution. Since you initially tagged this question as just JS, I've answered it with regular JS. Anyway, I believe it should be enough :)

Comment: Coffee use indent to declare function, but it's missing here. Maybe this is an indent bug, but without it, it's impossible to say... Can you give us the original formatted code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I managed to save the results of the calculation.

```
$scope.saveAll = ->
  payslips = []
  angular.forEach $scope.employments, (employment) ->
    payslip = employment.payslip
    payslip.gross_pay = ..........****calculation****.......
    payslips.push(payslip)

  Api.Batch.save(payslips)
```